# javascript: performing appendChild(node) and then trying to read node.clientWidth fails

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I have a trouble with DOM `appendChild()` method. I create a node, then append this node to a parent node, and then i want to read `node.clientWidth` property, but it returns 0, because the node is not drawn yet. Here is my code:

```js
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.textContent = 'some text';
parent.appendChild(node);
alert(node.clientWidth); //shows 0
```

I  tried `onload` and `onshow` events on the node, but they were not even triggered. I can use `setTimeout` and it's working, but this is not a perfect solution. Is there a good solution
for this problem?
Sorry for my bad English and thanks you so much!

**UPDATE**: Ok, i see my problem. Parent at that time was not appended to DOM. Sorry and thanks for your time

Comment: onload had to be helpful, but dom ready event is what you actually need to try, or embed code into html right after parent element

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating this. What browser are you using, and what context is this script running in (head, body, onload)? If I put it in the head, it fails with a TypeError since document.body doesn't exist yet. If I put it in the body, it works as expected.

Comment: Ok, i see my problem. Parent at that time was not appended to DOM. Sorry and thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted it to give you clientWidth as soon as the browser knew it you could do:

```
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.textContent = 'some text';
parent.appendChild(node);
var width = node.clientWidth;
while (width == 0) {
    width = node.clientWidth;
}
// stuff
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in an endless loop. It is strange that there is no event for this...

Comment: Usually you can check it immediately, are you waiting for the DOM to be loaded before appending the node?

Comment: Yes, this action is performed in window.onload callback. It is strange, because setTimeout for 2 miliseconds is enough, but while loop never ends. I'm afraid I'll have to perform setTimeout in loop...

Comment: falouu, your example works fine for me as written: http://jsfiddle.net/FScPz/ ... does this work for you? If so can you create an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Ok, i see my problem. Parent at that time was not appended to DOM. Sorry and thanks for your time